# Duplicate localDB under SQL Servers on my laptop

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

I've been running into an issue recently when I attempt any tutorials that involve using a SQL database, entity framework, dapper, etc.

When it comes time to publish a database, or utilize an ORM, I'm given duplicate options for the same localdb under SQL Servers. Furthermore, then I attempt to publish, the database doesn't show up under the localdb that I've chosen.

I'm wondering how I go about removing the other SQL Servers and just having the one available.

If you look at the image below, the Browse option gives me two of the same LocalDbs. Plus I also get a 3rd one under \ProjectModels. I'm wondering what's causing this and how it can be fixed since no matter which one I choose, the sql database I attempt to publish doesn't show up within any of them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My advice is not to use this method to publish the database. (right click to delete)

Please refer to this [official documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/copy-databases-to-other-servers?view=sql-server-ver16)

File-based databases like SQLite or SQL Server Express are designed to store their data in easily transferable files that can be served with your application/site.

`"Copy to Output Directory"` Property of the database file to `"Copy if newer"`. Just point the address to it.

If you are using a server-based database like SQL Server, MySQL, etc., you need to make sure that the target machine/environment has the same database server installed, and you need to write a deployment script to append the pre-populated data files to the server. This might be troublesome for you.

You can also refer to these links. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19670290/16764901),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31162015/16764901),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63994261/16764901)